# Coroutines duplicated threads with JMS thread pool

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

I have some logic, which uses JMS queue thread pool.
How it looks in general:

```
[request thread] -> jms -> JMS listener [thread pool] -> reactive web client
```

And now I'm getting duplication of messages (for example - errors)

```
ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-5 @coroutine#2]
ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-4 @coroutine#4]
ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 @coroutine#1]
ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3 @coroutine#3]
```

Such coroutines launched by `runBlocking`.

```
@JmsListener(destination = ...)
fun someHandleFunction(...) = runBlocking {
   someWebClientService.createRequest(...)
}

// SomeWebClientService class
suspend fun createRequest(...) = try {
   val response = webClient
       .post()
       .uri { ... }
       ...
       .exchange()
       .awaitFirst()

   // Check response status here
} catch (e: Exception) { 
   // Some error handling here
}
```

Yep, I know that in the case of `runBlockin` coroutines can [behave in such way](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher)... But why coroutines threads associated with new threads?

What is the problem with such duplications?

Comment: Is your question just why JMS doesn't allow the use of the same thread for these separate requests?

Comment: @Tenfour04 anyway, I want to build a bridge between JMS thread pool and web client request. And yep, why i have separate threads, not only one with coroutines (see error log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues were related to JMS configuration.

For some reason, without this config separate JMS threads worked on one single task

```
spring:
     artemis.embedded:
           persistent: true
           data-directory: ./target/some-queue-storage
           queues: ...
```